# Redirect to previously loaded page in codeigniter

Tags: php, redirect

I have a page to select district and school and when the page is submitted the employees of that school is listed below.And  and from there is an edit page to edit employee details. In that page I have a back button which must redirect to previous page where district, school and employees have to be preloaded.
I'm using codeigniter framework. I used the following code

$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo anchor($ref,' ');

Bu the problem is  the page is promting to select district and school .The preloaded values are not retaining in the page.Can you please tell how it could be done.

Comment: If I am right , you need the values in the field to be restored...

Comment: Use set value if you are trying to restore form fields

Comment: once you click the edit button in the list page, are u redirecting (using normal page reload) the user to new page and displaying the details to edit or else you are using ajax to display the edit form in same page ?

Answer (score 0):

To restore the form fields . you can use set_vale()

Example :

```
<input type = "text" name = "district" value = "<?php echo (set_value("district") != ""):set_value("district"):" "; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add bewlos lines in all pages before checking login status/session:

```
$current_url = current_url();
$CI->session->set_userdata('current_url',$current_url);
```

and after login :

redirect user to above page like :

```
if($this->session->userdata('current_url') != '')
{
   header('Location: '.$this->session->userdata('current_url'));
   exit();
}
else
{
   header('Location: '.get_client_url().'home');
   exit();
}
```